How to fix mouse position values to large in unity
I'm trying to make a game were the player moves towards the mouse. I set up a simple way to move the player using a Vector2.MoveTowards to move towards the Input.mousePosition. But my mouse position values are way to large and it still counts my position when my mores is off the game screen.
I tried using a Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint but It did not work after I implemented it (However I may have implemented it wrong as this is the first time I am using Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint).
public class PlayerMoveWithMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] float speed = 5f;
private Camera cam;
Vector3 point = new Vector3();
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
cam = Camera.main;
}
void Update()
{
point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.y, 
Input.mousePosition.x, cam.nearClipPlane));
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
point, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}


Try using a raycast instead, eg Camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition) and use that in a raycast to hit something in the scene.  ScreenToWorldPoint requires you to set the z component, which is the distance away from the camera.  If you simply pass the mouse position, your player will try to go to where the camera is.

However I may have implemented it wrong .. hard to tell for us without seeing your code .. please post a [mcve] .. in general: yes of course mouse position is usually in screen pixel space so you need to convert it first

@derHugo Sorry about that I added the code I used

Is your camera perspective or orthographic?

@derHugo orthographic

After working on it I figured out the problem was that I did not set the Z value to 0. And to fix the y and x value order
Here is the fixed code.
public class PlayerMoveWithMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] float speed = 5f;
private Camera cam;
Vector3 point = new Vector3();
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
 cam = Camera.main;
}
void Update()
{
point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, 
Input.mousePosition.y, cam.nearClipPlane));
point.z=0;
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
point, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

